# WinCE emulator shows Black Screen when trying to run

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-compact

I am new to WinCE.

I am trying to build an WinCE 6.0 Image using platform builder.

So I went Like this .

1. Visual Studio 2005 >> Platform Builder >> OS Design
2. Avilable BSP : CEPC X86
3. Custom Device
4. Actice sync and Cab File Insaller and
5. Finished.

Build >> Build OSDesign .
Make Runtime image .

In Device's I choose "Windows CE device " and in Device option 
Kernal Service Map >> Device Emulator
Debugger >> KdStub

Now After building and creating image when I click Attach devive , it comes up and shows me 
a Black screen. Not sure what mistake I am doing .

Packages I Installed :

> 1. Visual Studio 2005
> 2. Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1
> 3. Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista (if
>      applicable)
> 4. Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Platform Builder
> 5. Windows Embedded CE 6.0 SP1 (required if PB 6.0 Tools have been
>      installed)
> 6. Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R2
> 7. Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R3
> 8. Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Cumulative Product Update Rollup Package
>      (through 12/31/2010)
> 9. Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Monthly update August

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't selected properly the BSP, currently I am using WinCE 7.0, but from what I remember you should select a BSP called: [Device Emulator: ARMV4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee481215%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx) - something similar should be for a x86 - CEPC design. For example on WinCE 7.0 you have a BSP called VCEPC - Virtual CEPC that can be loaded in Virtual PC. The reason is that you have different drivers, different bootloader, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem that is not solved yet but searching a documentation around you can check if the KITL option in the project properties is ENABLED.

If it is then please try disabling it, rebuild the project and make new run-time image.

I hope this helps you.

My problem is listed here: [Black screen after booting WinCE 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808833/win-ce-6-0-run-time-image-after-booting-turns-black-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Since solving the same problem I agree with Patrik. In my case it was the KITL Option. After I disabled this option, my composed image continued booting. This MS article helped me out of the problem:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289160(v=vs.71).aspx#grfvsdtroubleshooting
Section "Emulator generated by Platform Builder boots with black screen"

Short: 
1. Start Platform Builder with your composed Platform
2. Select "Platform" on the menu bar.
3. Now click subitem "Settings"
4. Select the "Build Options" tab
5. Uncheck "Enable KITL (no IMGNOKITL=1)"