# Win CE 6.0 run-time image after booting turns black screen

Tags: windows-ce, boot

What can be the cause of my Windows CE 6.0 installation to turn to black screen after initial loading ?  I built the Win CE 6.0 myself. After initial screen displaying Win CE 6.0 logo with progress bar reaching 100% the screen turns black.

Is there any way to debug, test or emulate the run time image before deploying.

I have not a real hardware in my development environment to test it.
I just built the image and sent to the client for testing.

I based the Win CE image on Board Support Package from the ICOP company. The target touch panel is ICOP  with Vortex86DX chipset.

Every possible, permutation, combination results in black screen. I disabled all debuging techniques (KITL, ... ) without progress.

Please, give mi some advice where and how to find the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those who have similar problems as mine I will give the solution that worked for me.
In the Project properties\Building Options must be unchecked everything and specially KITL and all debugging options. In addition the project must be built in Release mode.