# Win CE 6.0 shows black screen at startup

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I'm building my own Windows CE 6.0 image (NK.bin) and after Windows has been loaded is the screen just black. When i attach a USB to the USB slave port on the device the window saying "USB client Status" shows up and the mouse is visible and i can control it together with the keyboard.

However, I'm stuck at this. I been reading a similar post to remove all settings in project properties according to [stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808833/win-ce-6-0-run-time-image-after-booting-turns-black-screen), without any result. I can't connect to the screen with "Windows CE Remote Zoom-in", but can connect with Remote Register and Remote Process.

Any clue?

Comment: Do you have Explorer in the OS and is it set to launch at startup?

Comment: In my platform builder, i can't find Explorer. Only Internet Explorer. I tried set explorer to startup but guess the issue is that i dont have it. How do i handle this?

Comment: I have one image NK.bin where explorer starts. I cant find the file explorer.exe there either so maybe i just need to start the program correctly? How do i do that?

Comment: I added all needed in HKLM\init - Launch20, Launch30, and Launch50 is explorer.exe with dependence on the other two.

Comment: Just figured out that i miss explorer.exe file.. how do i add this to the build?

Comment: Did you add the Shell from the catalog?  Explorer is the default sample shell.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!

Comment: Post what you did as an answer then.

Comment: I added explorer.exe to HKLM/init but the problem was that explorer was not included in the build. I had to choose the "standard" shell to include explorer, when i actually wanted the "thin client shell". This is still an issue to get some features from them both but at least this problem is solved and I can move on to next ;) Thanks again.

Comment: Please post it as an answer. That would save the time taken for reading through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I added explorer.exe to HKLM/init but the problem was that explorer was not included in the build. I had to choose the "standard" shell to include explorer, when i actually wanted the "thin client shell". This is still an issue to get some features from them both but at least this problem is solved and I can move on to next ;) Thanks again.